# Sharepoint 2013 Document library Edit Properties not opening in a dialog box

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepointdocumentlibrary

We are migrating to SP2013 from SP2010. In SP2010 environment, we were using our own custom webpart to view and edit properties with two buttons "View Properties" and "Edit Properties" as following:

```
 <asp:HyperLink CssClass="links" ID="HyperLink3" onclick="javascript:ViewAllProps();"
        runat="server">View Properties</asp:HyperLink>        
    <br />
    <asp:HyperLink CssClass="links" ID="HyperLink4" onclick="javascript:EditAllProps();"
        runat="server">Edit Properties</asp:HyperLink>
```

and they use to open in a dialog or in a page itself, according to the library settings.

But in SP2013 environment, it is not opening in dialog box even though library setting "Launch forms in a dialog?" is set to "Yes".

Can anyone help me point to the right direction?

Comment: You should ask this question on: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh, my bad. Thank you for pointing me to right place. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/162191/sharepoint-2013-document-library-edit-properties-not-opening-in-a-dialog-box